# Get chronological page order

Tags: theme-development

I just want to know if Is there a way to get **chronological** page order by page ID ??

```
$args = array('order' => 'ASC',
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
    );
    $the_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Now what i want to know is the number of order of each page

Comment: Could you elaborate? Do you mean in the order they were created? Or ordered by published date?

Comment: Are they not ordered this way when doing a post query by default? Or are you asking about a specific function? If so please update your question to clarify

Comment: @TheDeadMedic i mean the order they were created that means by published date

Comment: @TomJNowell Question updated

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`orderby` query parameter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters) coupled with `order`:

```
$pages_ordered_by_date = get_posts([
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type'      => 'page',
    'orderby'        => 'post_date',
    'order'          => 'ASC',
]);
```

Comment: No not that ,  I updated the question for more clarification

Comment: Can you explain how this doesn't give you what you want? I've read your question and this answer would give you what you want, if you want to use `WP_Query` instead then the parameters are exactly the same